# Symfony2: How to validate an entity by taking into account the currently logged in user?

Tags: validation, symfony

I'm doing a custom validation using callback inside the User entity.

Therefore I need to get the User object of the currently logged user.

In controller I can do it like this:

```
$user= $this->get('security.context')->getToken()->getUser();
```

But how should I do it inside the User entity?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you want to validate an object with any logic related to an external dependency (in your case the `@security.context` service to get the current user) ...  you should:

- create a **custom validation-constraint**
- create a **custom validator** service to be used by the constraint
- inject the `@security.context` service into the validator
- use this newly created validation constraint to validate your entity

The solution is described in the documentation chapter **[Validators with Dependencies](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/validation/custom_constraint.html#constraint-validators-with-dependencies)**

---

**[This video](https://www.google.de/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwiJ5uyc3uPLAhUBDywKHQj6BegQtwIIIzAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.youtube.com%2Fwatch%3Fv%3DKgM4VdZMA5E&usg=AFQjCNF9SAbD6_C_ro4arJePcz6Te6b-Pw)** shows why it's absolutely necessary to have the following RedBull validator.

**Model/Entity**

```
use FamilyGuy\Validator\Constraints\Peter as PeterIsNotAllowedToOrder;

class Order 
{
    /** @PeterIsNotAllowedToOrder/RedBull */
    public $drink;
```

**Config**

```
# app/config/services.yml
services:
    validator.red_bull:
        class: FamilyGuy\Validator\Constraints\Peter\RedBullValidator
        # for symfony < 2.6 use @security.context
        arguments: ["@security.token_storage"]
        tags:
            - name: "validator.constraint_validator"
              alias: "peter_red_bull_constraint_validator"
```

**Constraint**

```
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraint;

namespace FamilyGuy\Validator\Constraints\Peter;

/**
 * @Annotation
 */
class RedBull extends Constraint
{
    /** @var string */
    public $message = 'Peter... You are not allowed to order %drink%.';

    /** @return string */
    public function validatedBy()
    {
        // has to match the validator service's alias !
        return 'peter_red_bull_constraint_validator';
    }
}
```

**Validator:**

```
// For symfony < 2.6 use SecurityContextInterface
// use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\SecurityContextInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\Token\Storage\TokenStorageInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraint;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\ConstraintValidator;

namespace FamilyGuy\Validator\Constraints\Peter;

class RedBullValidator extends ConstraintValidator
{

    /** @var TokenStorageInterface|SecurityContextInterface */
    protected $tokenStorage;

    /** @param TokenStorageInterface|SecurityContextInterface $token_storage */
    public function __construct(TokenStorageInterface $token_storage)
    {
        $this->tokenStorage = $token_storage;
    }

    public function validate($drink, Constraint $constraint)
    {
        $currentUser = $this->tokenStorage->getToken()->getUser()->getName();

        if ($currentUser !== "Peter") {
            return;
        }

        if ( $drink !== "RedBull" ) {
             return
        }

        $this->context->buildViolation($constraint->message)
            ->setParameter('%drink%', $drink)
            ->addViolation()
        ;
    }
```

---

You can't and you shouldn't use the `Callback` constraint to validate against any external dependency.

Don't try to inject **any validation dependency** into your domain model or entities directly.

**Validation logic should be kept out of entities** in general.

Annotations are already some sort of soft-coupling between entities and the symfony validator. That's why it's recommended to use xml configuration for doctrine- and validation-mappings usually.

Comment: Thank you. But it doesn't work for me. SecurityContextInterface is seems to be deprecated since 2.6 or something. I'm using symfony3.

Comment: Updated the answer. With Symfony 2.6+ the `@security.token_storage` provides the `getToken()` method instead of `@security.context` ... but you could have been able to figure this out yourself ;) If my answer provides valuable insights you might consider accepting or at least upvoting it.

Comment: I'm new to symfony, so I couldn't figure it out by myself. Anyway, it works now!! Thank you very much! :)

Comment: New to symfony as well. Your way of explaining the problem was very clean and straightforward. Thank you very much. Do you have any other valuable insights about Symfony? Do you have any kind of tutorial written by your own? I would be very pleased to learn from your thinking. I like to do things the right way and you seem to know how that is :)